Not getting docker event on start or stop container
I have created a docker_event_notifier.js where I require 'dockerode' and 'docker-events', by this I can get start and connect event but not receiving '_message' or 'event'. I am using docker compose up -d to run container.
Here is the code:
const Docker = require('dockerode');
const DockerEvents = require('docker-events');

const docker = new Docker({ socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock' });

const emitter = new DockerEvents({ docker: docker, });

// Debug connection status
emitter.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Docker events stream.');
});

emitter.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected from Docker events stream.');
});

emitter.on('event', (event) => {
    console.log('Received Docker Event:', event);
});

emitter.on("_message", function(message) {
    console.log("got a message from docker: %j", message);
});

try {
    emitter.start();
    console.log('Started listening for Docker events...');
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error starting Docker events emitter:', err);
}

How can I get the event?
I tried using
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {      console.log("Going here");      try {           const event = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());           console.log('Event:', event);       } catch (parseErr) {           console.log('Failed to parse event:', parseErr);       } });
But no luck
ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root docker 0 Dec 25 16:50 /var/run/docker.sock

I might be looking at something old, but this doesn't list an event event and it looks like you should have a handler for start and stop. But it hasn't been updated in 10 years?!?

Yes, I tried that as well although it's not detecting start or stop event. @HansKilian Thanks for reply

I tried running your program and I get messages when a container is started or stopped (a _message with status start or stop).
